# two ways to change height or width in JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(selector).height(value)
$(selector).width(value)
```

We can use the above two ways to change the `height` or `width` of a `div` or element. but there is also another way, like

```
$(selector).css({"height": "100px", "width":"100px"})
```

since the second way can be applied to all css element, why the first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one major difference: in `width()` and `height()` you can use function as parameter which returns a value

```
.height( function(index, height) )
```

Comment: function(index, height)A function returning the height to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old height as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set. taken from http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, there's often more than one way to do it.

`.height` and `.width` are useful convenience methods which simplify programming, while `.css` is the general method that encompasses all of that functionality (at the expense of being somewhat more cumbersome).